# How to query the all time high market cap for an ERC20 contract?

Tags: python, ethereum, blockchain, erc20, pyrogram

I saw some TG token scanner bots which show the all time high market cap for ERC20 tokens and I was not able to find out how they do this.

Web3.py doesn't have this feature and I was also not able to find an API for this query.

Anybody out there who knows how to fetch this info?

Thanks

Tried several API's which show the historical price per block but it was too exhausting for my machine and needs.

Comment: just fetch it once a day and cache it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.